# Button click in iFrame on Page Load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an embedded iframe (a map) and need the search button to be clicked on page load to display the search results. When clicking the search button on the map the action does not change the url.

Has anyone tried this action before and is it possible? The button has an id="search1" and the scripts I have tried are below. First is a basic doc ready and the second sets a delay (I was hoping once the map loads the script would fire and initiate the search).

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
   document.getElementById("search1").click();
});
</script>

<script>
$("document").ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        $("#search1").trigger('click');
    },20);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Is there an actual `click` handler for that button - or are you trying to invoke the native functionality?

Comment: I need to have the results display on the map by having the <button="search1"></button> clicked on page load. The entire map is  an iframe. Sorry, I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Show us a working example, you can create one here: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I'm reading more and seeing a possibility of the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy  Same origin policy being an issue. I am seeing a possiblity of injecting javascript into the header but not sure if it could apply because of the above policy.